# Substr() removes use of index

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Say field "Name" is in Table1 and "NameDetail" is in Table2. They are both index.

```
Name  NameDetail  
Jack  JackJohnson  
Kent  KentJacobs
```

I am trying to do a join on "Name" = "NameDetail". But since they are not exactly the same. I am really trying to do a join on "Name" = substr(NameDetail,0,4); Assuming that it will always be the first 4 characters. Using substr() will remove the use of index which slows down the query significantly.

I tried using wildcard where "NameDetail" like 'Name'||'%' but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Also, I am a user of the database. Not a developer so i would not be able to create new index. Be really grateful if someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Which table is the driver - i.e. which way do you want to join, and which is more selective? What does "didn't work" mean for the wildcard approach - did you actually run what you've typed there with the string literal `'Name'`, or `"NameDetail" like "Name"||'%'` with the column identifier?

Comment: You might want to try creating [Function-Based Index](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes). Also, keep in mind, that a Function-Based Index [cannot contain the value `NULL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505). You can use `NVL` function, though, to ensure your index always had a value different than `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an index on an expression in the second table.  Do note that the first character of a substring is denoted by `0` rather than `1`.  So, for your case:

```
create index idx_table2_namedetail4 on table2(substr(NameDetail, 1, 4));
```

Oracle should then use the index for this join:

```
select . . .
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = substr(NameDetail, 1, 4);
```

Comment: I would not be able to create index since I am just a user of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you enclosed the field "Name" in quotes for the wildcard search as you have shown, then it didn't work because it would be looking for the string literal 'Name', not the contents of the column Name. NameDetail LIKE Name||'%' on the other hand works:

```
with nam as (select 'Jack' nam from dual union all select 'Kent' nam from dual)
    ,namDet as ( select 'JackJohnson' nameDetail from dual union all select 'KentJAcobs' nameDetail from dual)
select n.nam, d.* 
from nam n 
   join namDet d
on d.nameDetail like n.nam||'%'       

NAM  NAMEDETAIL  
Jack JackJohnson 
Kent KentJAcobs
```

Unfortunately, this will still likely have some performance issues over large data sets as there is no way to do a fast index-to-index join for partial matches.